# SAS distinct level

Tags: macros

```
data test1;
input var1$ var2$ ;
datalines;

1 a 
2 a 
3 a 
1 b 
2 b 
1 c
;
run;
```

How can I create a macro var that contains all levels of var2?
For example:
    %Let new_var = a b c;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, I think you can try using proc sql for this.

```
proc sql;
select distinct var2 into :new_var from test1;
quit;
```